# Use fetched API data outside of the function

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

To make my code cleaner I want to use fetched API data in a few different functions, instead of one big. Even though I 've did manage to reffer to that data in other functions, the problem is the API im a fetching throws different, randomized results every time it is called. And so the output from userData() does not equal that from userData2(), even though my intention is different and I'd like the *result* variable contents to be the same between functions.

```js
const getData = () =>
  fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10").then((response) =>
    response.json()
  );

const useData = async () => {
  const result = await getData();
  console.log(result);
};

const useData2 = async () => {
  const result = await getData();
  console.log(result);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getData()` function returns a promise. One fun fact about promises is that while they can only *resolve* once, that resolved value can be accessed and used as many times as you want.

```js
const dataPromise = getData();

const useData = async () => {
  const result = await dataPromise;
  console.log(result);
};

const useData2 = async () => {
  const result = await dataPromise;
  console.log(result);
};
```

Using `await` resolves the promise value, the equivalent of...

```js
dataPromise.then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
// or `dataPromise.then(console.log)` if you like brevity
```

---

I like to point this out about the [fetch-api](/questions/tagged/fetch-api)... you should always check the [Response.ok](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) property

```js
const getData = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10");
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`${res.status}: ${await res.text()}`);
  }
  return res.json();
};
```

Comment: Thanks!! I 'll keep that in mind from now on.